# How to sign in with different types of user in flutter and firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to sign in with different types of users, I have firebase authenticator to sign in and made a database with users and userType as a field, so anyone knows a function that shows different interface with different types of user ?
My Code :

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  var email;
  var password;
  var username;
  var gender;
  var userType;
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;
      void login() async {
        final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        firebaseAuth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
            .then((result) {
          {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/homepage');
          }
        }).catchError((err) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Error"),
                  content: Text(err.message),
                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Ok"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              });
        });
      }
      void getUserData() async {
        try {
          firestoreInstance
              .collection('Users')
              .document(usernameController.text)
              .get()
              .then((value) {
            setState(() {
              email = (value.data)['email'];
              password = (value.data)['password'];
              gender = (value.data)['gender'];
              username = (value.data)['username'];
              userType = (value.data)['userType'];
            });
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to navigate to a different page after signing in, that'd be something like:

```
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
firebaseAuth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
    .then((result) {
  firestoreInstance
      .collection('Users')
      .document(usernameController.text)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
      var userType = (value.data)['userType'];
      if (userType == "firstType") {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/homepage');
      }
      else if (userType == "secondType") {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/anotherpage');
      }
    });
  }
```