# In flutter how to redirect to specific dashboard based on the type of user Sign In?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

here I want to Navigate a user to specific dashboard after Login, How I can implement logic for this??
I have a requirement in my application to include two types of users. one type of user (tutor) will have access to a different dashboard after logging in and the second type (student) of user will have access to a different dashboard ? The login screen is the same for both the users. Based on the login credentials, In real time database?

```
  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    var password = passwordController.text;
    var email = emailController.text;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog(
      context,
      dialogTransitionType: DialogTransitionType.Bubble,
      title: Text('Signing In'),
      message: Text('Please wait'),
    );

    progressDialog.show();

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      //progressDialog.dismiss();

      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
 
         Here i want redirect to specific dashboard based on the type of user Sign In?

      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      progressDialog.dismiss();
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'User not found', backgroundColor: Colors.red);
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Wrong password', backgroundColor: Colors.red);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

},

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't have a type of user, but here's one way to implement this by using Auth + Firestore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62534419/how-to-sign-in-with-different-types-of-user-in-flutter-and-firebase

Answer (score 2):

#### You are using firebase authentication with email and password.

It manages users with the same Model that is *User*. So it is impossible for you to handle this redirection.

But the most easiest approach is to save user's data to firestore after authentication (you save email, name, isTeacher,....). **[NB: The ID of the firestore document should be the uniqueid of the user after authentication]**

After the user has been authenticated, you call a method getUser() that will return wheter your **custom userModel**.

Finally, if the isTeacher is true navigate to Teacher dashboard else navigate to user homescreen

Comment: Baimam Boukar can you create a model for me please